# Assignment of strings does not work

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I want to pass a string between two viewcontroller but is always (null)

My code

GridViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface GridViewController : UIViewController {

 }

 @property (nonatomic, strong)UILabel * labelTitle;

 @end
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       NSString *currow =[self.mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSLog(@"the string is %@", currow);
       //the string is Grappe, Brandy and Cognac

       GridViewController * grid = [[GridViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GridViewController~iPhone" bundle:nil];

       grid.labelTitle.text = currow;

       NSLog(@"the string is %@", grid.labelTitle.text);
       //the string is (null)

       NSLog(@"the string is  %@", currow);
       //the string is Grappe, Brandy and Cognac

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:grid animated:YES];

 }
```

Comment: grid.labelTitle is nil at the time you do  grid.labelTitle.text = currow;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`labelTtitle` is a GUI element of the `GridViewController`, it wont get any value when you try to access in other class, You should better try to create a `NSString`  in your `GridViewController` and assign the value to this string in the other class, but when you load your `viewDidLoad` for the `GridViewController` then assign this string to your label like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    self.labelTitle.text=self.stringYouCreated;

}
```

In `ViewController.m` assign value to string property you created in `GridViewcontroller` like this

```
   grid.stringYouCreated = currow;
```

Comment: I add grid.labelTitle =[[UILabel alloc]init]; within in the method and now works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

There is no existent instance of labelTitle at the time you assigned the text to it. The Label get instantiated from xib, and only then it can hold the value.

Answer (score 1):

Your `labelTitle` seemse to be nil. It should have been created in the `viewDidLoad` method of `GridViewController`